# Inside of MatterialApp. MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to set a drawer size dynamically.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './screens/tab_screen.dart';

//widgets
import './widgets/main_drawer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: TabWidget(),
        endDrawer: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
          child: MainDrawer(),
        ),
      ),
      title: "Ali Azad",
      // routes: {
      //   '/': (_) => TabWidget(),
      // },
    );
  }
}
```

but I have got this error = MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look better in your code, you will see that your build method is called with a context and by the time of that call, there isn't any previous Widget, which mean that your MaterialApp doesn't exist yet when your build is called, so that BuildContext doesn't have any previous MaterialApp, you can solve this just by splitting your code like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      title: "Ali Azad",
    );
  }
}

// This Home Widget will be a child of MaterialApp, and the BuildContext has access to this Material widget.
class Home extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabWidget(),
      endDrawer: Container(
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
         child: MainDrawer(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you don't want to create another Widget, then you should use a [Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXNOkIuSYuA) widget that will generate a new BuildContext for you. Your Widget would look like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Builder(
    build: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: TabWidget(),
        endDrawer: Container(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
           child: MainDrawer(),
        )
      );
    }
  ),
  title: "Ali Azad",
);
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. your answer helped me to know why it happened. was facing same issue and though i solved by creating another widget, was not sure why without this, it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

put your `Container` widget inside a `Builder` widget or create a separate widget an assign it to `MaterialApp` `home` parameter, this way you get the `context` of `MaterialApp` widget, the `context` you are now using doesn't have a `MaterialApp`.